Query the latest nested object in OpenSearch/ElasticSearch
I'm using OpenSearch to allow users to search a complex data structure. One of the use cases requires me to display records only if the latest nested object meets the requirements, but google and the docs are being rather unhelpful. Example data structure:
{
  "id": 0,
  "nestedObject": [
    {
      "date": ...,
      "boolean": ...,
    }
    {
      "date": ...,
      "boolean": ...,
    }
  ]
}

the pseudo search for this would be:
nestedObject.date == max(nestedObject.date) && nestedObject.boolean === true
If this is possible, how would I go about it?

The simplest way to do it would be to add an additional boolean field to the nested objects and set it to True for the latest nested object during indexing. This way your pseudo search would become:
nestedObject.isLatest == true && nestedObject.boolean == true


Thanks, that's essentially how I'm handling it now. I was hoping to be able to be able to append data to the index without having to recreate the entire document

What do you think happens when you add an new nested document? You are recreating the entire document. When you add an additional nested object what happens internally is elasticsearch is deleting the old root document and ALL its nested documents and re-creates a new root document and ALL its nested documents plus one that you just added in a new segment.

yes, but that is on the elastic search side. my goal with appending to the document is to reduce the load at the source. Generating the entire document requires me to load data from over 600 tables in our relational DB. just the section in one of the nested objects touches up to 50. All told it's orders of magnitude difference in load times several hundred thousand updates a day. It adds up fast :)

You can make this modification on the elasticsearch side in the ingest pipeline or by using update script
